# Adding delay on jms message processing

Tags: hibernate, activemq-classic, xa, atomikos

I am using atomikos with Hibernate and ActiveMQ. My transaction involves,message being commited to DB and sent to queue. JMS reveiver then reads the message and calls get from db.

There are cases where Atomikos has commited to Queue but hibernate commit is still in progress , in the mean time get query is fired from receiver.I tried to find if there is way we can specify commit order in XA transaction but answer seems to be no  reading [this](http://pauldone.blogspot.in/2016/03/xatransactionseventuallyconsistent.html).

So I was thinking is there a way we can add some lag in message processing so that message is icked up only after 5sec by the time commit would have been successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

activemq support delayed message, see http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html

2 things you should do:

first is adding schedulerSupport in activemq.conf

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" schedulerSupport="true">
```

and then add a `AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY` property when sending.

like `textMessage.setLongProperty("AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY", 5000);`

Comment: Yes, this adds the requested delay, but I'm not sure this answers the question about the introduced lag beeing a good idea.

Comment: Is there a way we can specify commit order of participant of xa in JBOSS? I know XA doesn't specify commit order of participant. But application server like websphere have commit order defined where jdbc is always comited prior to JMS. Is there anything which can help ordering commit order,  anything provided by atomikos or XA or Jboss.

Comment: In my case it was `message.setLongProperty("_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY", 5000);`